# How to inject HTML using Angular 1.4?

Tags: angularjs

I have a data source that contains an array of raw HTML strings.  I must display these in a page to the user.

Being a bit new with Angular, the first thing I tried was this:

```
<div ng-repeat="html in ctrl.html" ng-bind="html"></div>
```

This causes Angular to escape my HTML and display it as a string.  It isn't what I need, but at least it shows that Angular is, indeed, loading the data.

Doing a Google search, I read about the ng-bind-html-unsafe directive, which I understand is supposed to inject text into an HTML document without escaping or sanitizing it in any way, which is what I want because I must trust our data source.

```
<div ng-repeat="html in ctrl.html" ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>
```

This doesn't work, either.  It just shows me a blank page.  When I open the document inspector, I see that there is a div tag for each entry in the HTML array, but the divs are all blank.

Doing more Google-fu, I found discussions about calling methods on $scope to make Angular play nice with this.  They say that ng-bind-html-unsafe is deprecated.

With all the talk about different ways to do what I need with different versions of Angular, how do I do this with today's version: 1.4?

Comment: try to inject $sce to your controller and inject the html with   $sce.trustAsHtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to "sanitize" your html's..

Example:

```
angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
       .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
         this.html = array with your htmls;

         this.sanitizeHtml = function(html) {
           return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
         };
       }]);
```

Then

```
<div ng-repeat="html in ctrl.html" ng-bind-html="ctrl.sanitizeHtml(html)"></div>
```

I think it will work

Answer (score 1):

use **ngSanitize** module...

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
```

[see this link. this work perfect](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MUtDEe0UdNl96QVXWSp?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

In view

```
<div ng-repeat="html in ctrl.html" ng-bind-html="ctrl.sanitizeHtml(html)"></div>
```

In controller

```
myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

This will work